# Simulate buttonpresses with a discord-bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, botframework, discord-buttons

I currently work on a discord bot with the functionality to react to specific messages of other bots.
Right now i am stuck at the part where my bot can press buttons embedded in another message.

I can find the button objects through message.components[0].children.

What i am missing is a function/method that lets my bot click the button.
I thought about spoofing user-input, but i have no clue where i would get a interactiontoken from that auto renews itself

Example for understanding my problem:
Bot A (ticket bot) creats following message:
[image]

Bot B (my bot) needs to click on the blue button with the custom_id "ticket" and the fake name with the "letter Open a ticket!", so that ticket bot creates a ticket

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    print(message)
    
    if message.embeds:
        if message.components:
           print("Button(-s) exist")
           if message.components[0].children[0].custom_id == '<custom id of the button you want to press>'
              <Stuff to press the button>
```

Comment: Not possible; Discord bots cannot press buttons, unless you're talking about self-botting.

Comment: is it possible to send an http request for an button interaction as the discord client does when a user presses the button? give it the channel, message and button id aswell as an interaction token of a user...

Comment: Try `.click()`. I don't think it's there in the discord.py API; just saw it here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_selfbots/comments/tuchc6/how_to_click_buttons_in_discord_py_rebase_branch/?rdt=33788

Comment: sadly does not work.      
message.components[0].children[0].click()
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'click'